# Let $f $ be a continuous function such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\{x : f(x) = k\} $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f $ be a continuous function such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\{x : f(x) = k\} $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

$\{x : f(x) \neq k\} =\{x : f(x) < k\}\cup \{x : f(x) > k\}$

since $\{x : f(x) < k\}$ and $ \{x : f(x) > k\}$ are both open then $\{x : f(x) \neq k\} $ is open.

Then the complement of $\{x : f(x) \neq k\} $ i.e $\{x : f(x) = k\} $ is closed

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks correct to me, though I would have said simply $f^{-1}(k)$ is closed because $f$ is continuous and {$k$} is closed

Answer (score 4):

I believe your answer is correct.

More simply, you could have said $f^{-1}(k)$ is closed because $f$ is continuous and {$k$} is closed.

[A map of a metric space such as $\mathbb R$ to a metric space such as $\mathbb R$ is continuous

if and only if the inverse map of any closed (open) set is closed (respectively, open).]

Comment: Doesn't this approach assume Hausdorffness?

Comment: @EEEB, Yes, $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology is a Hausdorff space. So a singleton is a closed set.

Comment: @EEEB: Not Hausdorffness, just [$T_1$-ness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).

Answer (score 2):

It is correct if you really know that $\{x: f(x)<k\}$ and $\{x: f(x)>k\}$ are open. This is not absolutely trivial. I believe it would be a bit easier simply to prove that the set contains its closure. If $x_n\to x$ and $f(x_n)=k$ for all $n$ then by continuity $f(x)=k$ as well.